# Python six library error while using spynner

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install, spynner

I installed python, pip and easy_install on my computer.
and with pip command installed spynner but i've got an error with autopy installation,
but i solved it by using easy_install and after installation, i tried to use spynner but it give me an error with crashing...

Here's what i've got

`import spynner
br = spynner.Browser()
br.load("http://www.google.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner\browser.py", line 1674, in createRequest
    url = six.u(toString(request.url()))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 589, in u
    return unicode(s.replace(r'\', r'\\'), "unicode_escape")
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

On my Windows 7 64bit Ultimate and Python 2.7.8 64bit

I tried 32bit python also but gave me same error.
Anyone can solve this errror?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My immediate solution was to edit the u() method of the six module.

Originally it was:

```
def u(s):
    return unicode(s.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\'), "unicode_escape")
```

I changed it to:

```
def u(s):
    try:
        return unicode(s.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\'), "unicode_escape")
    except TypeError as e:
        if "decoding Unicode is not supported" in str(e):
            return unicode(s.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\'))
```

It's just a workaround. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker found solution.

Changing installation method.

1. Install Python
2. Download setuptools, spynner
3. Install setuptools using ez_setup.py
4. Install spynner
5. Install PyQt4

Maybe PyQt4 should be installed at last